# Ellipsis After Certain Number or Characters with Word Boundaries

Tags: php, regex, ellipsis, word-boundary

I'm trying to put an ellipsis (…) to shorten long descriptions and want to have word boundaries.

Here's my current code [eval.in](https://eval.in/508397):

```
# Assume $body is a long text.
$line = $body;
if(strlen($body) > 300 && preg_match('/^.{1,300}\b/su', $body, $match)) {
    $line = trim($match[0]) . "&hellip;";
}
echo $line;
```

This actually works pretty well and I like it except that there are times when the word boundary has a punctuation after it.

If I use the code above, I get results like the following:

`This is a long description…` or `I have punctuations,…`. I would love to remove the punctuation after the last word before putting the ellipsis.

Help?

Comment: Try matching the trailing punctuation with `'/^(.{1,300})\b\p{P}*/su'` and only use `trim($match[1]) . "&hellip;";`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Didn't work - [eval.in](https://eval.in/508404)

Comment: @Dagon From what I understand the `wordwrap` function does it doesn't seem like the right choice here.

Comment: Is CSS an option? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: @Hatchet I don't mind having the solution in CSS but the very first thing I read from that page made me say "No". `All the following are required, so the text must be in a single straight line that overflows a box where that overflow is hidden.` I have multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your fixed approach:

```
$body = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu congue ex. Nunc sem arcu, fermentum vel feugiat quis, consequat nec enim. Quisque et pulvinar velit, et laoreet justo. Integer quis sapien ac turpis mattis lobortis at at metus. Vestibulum euismod turpis odio, id luctus quam pharetra, at, et. Sed finibus, nunc at ultricies posuere, dui mauris aliquet quam, eget aliquet ligula libero a turpis. Pellentesque eu diam sodales, sollicitudin leo et, sagittis magna. Donec feugiat, velit quis condimentum porttitor, enim sapien varius elit, sit amet pretium risus turpis vitae massa. Sed ac ligula sit amet lorem scelerisque tristique a id ex. Nullam maximus tincidunt magna, vel molestie lectus tempus non. Sed euismod placerat ultricies. Morbi dapibus augue ut odio faucibus, vel maximus nisl pharetra. Aliquam hendrerit dolor in ipsum pharetra, eget tincidunt lacus ultrices.";

$line = $body;
if(strlen($body) > 300 && preg_match('/^(.{1,300})(?!\w)\b\p{P}*/su', $body, $match)) {
    $line = trim($match[1]) . "…";
}
echo $line;
```

See [eval.in demo](https://eval.in/508418)

As I noted in the comments, you can match the punctuation (optionally, with `\p{P}*`), but I forgot that `\b` can match both trailing *and* leading word boundary. By restricting the `\b` with the negative lookahead `(?!\w)` (like `(?!\w)\b`) we only match the *trailing* word boundary.

Besides, the capturing group (`(...)`) is added to the pattern so that we only *capture* into Group 1 the string with trailing punctuation trimmed out, and the value can be accessed with `$match[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$body = preg_replace('/^(.{0,299}\w)\b.*/su', '$1&hellip;', $body);
```

- [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJ1gE5/1)
- [Code Demo](https://eval.in/508419)

`\w` before `\b` ensures we don'e add `ellipsis` after a non-word character

Comment: Effectively it is the same regex that you originally had but just `preg_replace` instead of `preg_match`