# How to char limit a message in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, performance, regex-group

I am trying to write a simple function to crop a given message to a specific length but at the same time not to cut the words in between and no trailing spaces in the end.

Example:

**Input String**: The quick brown fox jumped over the fence, **K**: 11

**Output**: The quick

Here is what I have tried:

```
  function crop(message, K) {
  var originalLen = message.length;
  if(originalLen<K)
  {
      return message;
  }
  else
  {
      var words = message.split(' '),substr;

      for(var i=words.length;i > 0;i--)
       {

           words.pop();

            if(words.join(' ').length<=K)
            {
              return words.join(' ');
            }
       }


  }
}
```

This function works fine but I am not very happy with the implementation. Need suggestions on the performance aspects and will there be a case where this won't work?

Comment: do you have an example of the unsplitted string? ... and the wanted result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shorten string without cutting words in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454235/shorten-string-without-cutting-words-in-javascript)

Comment: @Herohtar yes but please read the lines below the question: ```This function works fine but I am not very happy with the implementation. Need suggestions on the performance aspects and will there be a case where this won't work?```

Comment: @NinaScholz Added an example in the question!

Comment: I use this regex to crop text with word boundaries `'/^(.{1,300})(?!\w)\b\p{P}*/su'` - 300 being my length. Taken from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023508/ellipsis-after-certain-number-or-characters-with-word-boundaries

Comment: What do you want to know that isn't covered in the duplicate? There are multiple solutions listed there that are more performant than string splitting and loops.

Comment: You might get better answers from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @uom-pgregorio never knew something like that existed! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This one gets the job done **without** using any for loops

```js
function crop(message, K) {
  var originalLen = message.length;
  if(originalLen<K)
  {
      return message;
  }
  else
  {
    var words = message.split(' '); 
    var splitWords = message.substring(0, K).split(' ');

    if( words[splitWords.length - 1] != splitWords[splitWords.length - 1])
     return splitWords.slice(0, splitWords.length - 1).join(' ');
    else
     return splitWords.join(' ');
  }
}

var str = "The quick brown fox jumped over the fence";
console.log(crop(str, 11));
```

Comment: This is pretty good, but there are some edge cases you're not considering. Ex.: str = "The quick brown fox jumped over the fence, bro"; and crop(str, 13) return "The quick bro". I know this isn't within the Question, but I'm assuming the provided test case isn't the only thing the OP is going use.

Comment: @computercarguy, thank you so much for finding the mistake, I have updated the code which now takes care of the edge case that you suggested

Answer (score 1):

You could check the length of the new string and increment an index for slicing the array.

```js
function crop(message, l) {
    var parts = message.split(/\s+/),
        i = 1;

    if (message.length < l) return message;
    while (parts.slice(0, i).join(' ').length < l) i++;
    return parts.slice(0, i - 1).join(' ');
}

console.log(crop('The quick brown fox jumped over the fence', 11)); // 'The quick'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reviewed your code!

[Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz)'s answer is really great!

---

However, [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/tSjyyG/1) might help you to do so:

```
([A-z0-9\s]{1,11})(\s)(.*)
```

This expression is relaxed from the right and has three capturing groups with just a list of chars that I have just added in the first capturing group and I'm sure you might want to change that list, maybe similar to:

```
([A-Za-z0-9\s]{1,11})(\s)(.*)
```

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Performance Test

This JavaScript snippet shows the performance of that expression using a simple 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the fence';
 const regex = /([A-z0-9\s]{1,11})(\s)(.*)/gm;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$1");
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

#### Testing Code

```js
const regex = /([A-z0-9\s]{1,11})(\s)(.*)/s;
const str = `The quick brown fox jumped over the fence`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```